# Is there a way to only have 1 checked radio button at a time HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have seen others on Stack Overflow asking the same question, but the answer remains the same: "use the `name` attribute."
This is not working for me, here is my code:

```
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="radio" name="1">
    <input type="radio" name="2">
</form>
```

Is there an alternative/something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If correctly written that is the **One and Only function of a Radio Button**? Give then all the same `name=` attribute and that is what will happen

Comment: A [useful resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: *"Is there an alternative/something I'm doing wrong?"* - HTML wise, nope. PHP wise, is another story; where's that? You used the tag for it.

Comment: *"but the answer remains the same: "use the name attribute.""* - So use the same name perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have the SAME name for both buttons like this:

```
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="radio" name="one">
    <input type="radio" name="one">
</form>
```

Comment: As PHP variables cannot start with a numeric it would be a good idea to use an alphanumeric name rather than a simple numeric `name="1"` -> `name="one"` _Not my DV_

Comment: I'm not sure why this has one downvote, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="">
  <p>Please select your Age:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="below_18" name="age" value="below_18">
  <label>Below 18</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="18_25" name="age" value="18_25">
  <label>15-25</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="above_25" name="age" value="above_25">
  <label>above 25</label><br>
</form>
```